# I have a problem with unity 2d lights and shadows problem

Tags: unity-game-engine

The shadows and lighting are working very well in unity, but it's not working correctly on the phone. What's wrong?

I'm using Point Light 2D(light 2d(experimental))
[image]
[image]

Comment: the light is expanded outside the border of the room, right ?

Comment: @JustARandomWibuu yes that's the problem,

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust the quality settings for android.
In project settings> Quality.